# How do I remove gradle support from an intellij project?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have a scala/sbt project, and there is a build.gradle file from when I was experimenting one time. Intellij saw the build.gradle and has enabled gradle for the project. Can I turn off gradle for the project?

I have deleted my build.gradle and any gradle directories in my project but I keep getting messsages like the below, so I'm guessing there is a setting in intellij I need to turn off.

```
7:31 pm The IDE modules below were removed by the Gradle import:
                knot-alpha

                You can open dialog to select the ones you need to restore.
```

Comment: Delete the file, reimport the project.

Comment: This doesnt work. Ive deleted my gradle files, restarted, and the gradle build tool is still messing with my project in the background

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Close the project
2. Remove all Gradle related files and directories:

   - `build.gradle`
   - `settings.gradle`
   - `gradle.properties`
   - `gradle/`
3. Delete the hidden `.idea/` directory
4. Reimport project

Comment: Removing the .idea directory is overkill. The answer from @ahuemmer about removing the .idea/grade.xml file seems to be enough.

Answer (score 16):

In addition to Fracisco Mateos answer:

It should be enough to remove the `gradle.xml` from the hidden `.idea` directory. This will remove the Gradle "nature" of the project in IntelliJ without having to delete all your workspace metadata.

Removing the `build.gradle`, `settings.gradle`, `gradle.properties` and `gradle` directory probably isn't necessary, but, of course, makes sense in order to have a clean project.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, way less invasive.